# What is the strategy to maximize peace in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

How to minimize total war casualties for all nations in Civilization 5? It comes to my mind that it is to have domination victory as fast as possible, but may there be other strategies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set map generator settings to ensure isolation of major Civs for as much time as possible (one per archipelago, less city states), then focus on Science and based on your advancements there pursue one of victory options (like Diplomatic or Scientific).

Comment: Good idea. Isolation is indeed an option.